# Titanium: get html source code

Tags: html, titanium

I am making an app in Titanium in which I wish to get HTML source code from an URL and return it as a string. I have tried to do the following:

```
function getHTML(URL) {
  var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
      onload: function(){
          Ti.API.info("Received HTML!");
          return this.responseText;
      },
      onerror: function(e){
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('Internetconnection failed. Try again later.');
      },
      timeout : 5000
  });
  client.open("GET", URL);
  client.send();
}
```

However, when I run this code, it seems as if the function returned nothing.
Your help would be most appreciated.
P.S. I need HTML source code specifically so using anything like JQuery won't really help me.

Answer (score 0):

As the function `onload` is asynchronous, it indeed doesn't return anything. You would have to use a callback function to make it work

```
function getHTML(URL, callback) {
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(){
        Ti.API.info("Received HTML!");
        if (callback){
             callback(this.responseText);
        }
    },
    onerror: function(e){
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('Internetconnection failed. Try again later.');
    },
    timeout : 5000
    });
    client.open("GET", URL);
    client.send();
}
```

So to call it, do this:

```
getHTML('http://google.com', function(html){
     console.log('got html!', html);
});
```

Comment: I did this and html is still undefined.